# Stream through gstreamer using GPU in Windows

Tags: windows, streaming, gpu, gstreamer, vp8

I'm trying to stream in windows through the next pipeline of gstreamer:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -m ksvideosrc do-stats=TRUE ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw ! vp8enc threads=4 ! rtpvp8pay ! udpsink host=224.1.1.1 port=5000 auto-multicast=true
```

But this consumes a lot of CPU process, I want to know if in windows it is possible to use the gpu to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intel Media SDK(msdk). This library is in bad plugin but is not in standard gstreamer windows release. you must build gstreamer on windows.